# Error 2400 when trying to transfer domain to joker.com registry

Tags: domain-transfer

I am trying to transfer a domain I bought to my domain name registry (joker.com).

I have received the AUTH-ID from the other party. The domain is not locked.

After a few minutes of finishing the transfer initialisation I receive an automatic email from the registry with the following error:

> Transfer could not be requested due to: `ERROR[-2400]<2400>`

I am not able to find any concise info on what this means.

Comment: "to my domain name registry" - you mean _registrar_. The "registry" is the organisation that controls the TLD (in this case, ICANN). The domain registrar to whom you are transferring this domain should be able to tell you what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2400 is a typical EPP error that means "Command Failed", see RFC5730. Just by itself it is mostly useless, normally the registry gives the registrar more information about what happened, or at least the registrar can ask the registry what is happening.

This is completely opaque to final client.

I doubt, like DocRoot, that the registry sent you any email, especially like the one you quote. It is more probably the future registrar, and indeed you should query it for details on what is happening, since that specific email is not crystal clear.

Since you are not providing the domain name being transfered and not even the TLD noone here can really help you more, and the question itself is probably offtopic anyway.